# Forms(frmName) NOT WORKING

Tags: windows, excel, vba, ms-office

I am trying to use a string variable instead of hardcoding the forms name as below.

```
FrmMainControl.Controls
```

but want to use this.

```
Forms("FrmMainControl").Controls
```

However, i get the error Sub or Function not defined. Please help. This is in VBA btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the form is `load`ed you can search the `UserForms` collection;

```
Dim form As UserForm: Set form = getInstanceOfLoadedUfrm("frmMainControl")
If Not form Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox form.Controls.Count
Else
    '//load
    Set form = UserForms.Add("frmMainControl")
    MsgBox form.Controls.Count
End If

Function getInstanceOfLoadedUfrm(name As String) As UserForm
name = UCase$(name)
For Each form In UserForms
    If (Ucase$(form.name) = name) Then
        Set getInstanceOfLoadedUfrm = form
    End If
Next
End Function
```